# Cython Doubly Linked list printing in order

Tags: python, c, cython

Hi I am building a doubly linked list structure I am looking to print my test names/words in alphabetical order.

The final product should look like this:

`BRAIDEN`
`BRANT`
`DAVE`
`KIM`

Currently `show_all` will display the last entry copied over all previous entries.

*Example: If "DAVE" was entered in last all the output would be:*

`DAVE`
`DAVE`
`DAVE`
`DAVE`

If I print within the `create()` function I get the output:

`BRAIDEN`
`BRANT`
`KIM`
`DAVE`

which is not alphabetical order but rather the order I entered them in.

*Note: my doubly linked list as of now does not seem to be printing through its structure. What I mean is you could just simply print the nodes or call `show_all` either way as of right now it is not printing through the structure it is as if they are being printed individually.*

**Program.pyx**

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

cdef struct Node
cdef struct Node:
    char* word
    Node* prev
    Node* next

cdef class DoublyLinkedList:

    cdef Node* head
    cdef Node* tail
    cdef Node* last_node
    cdef Node* next_node

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.head = NULL
        self.tail = NULL
        self.last_node = NULL
        self.next_node = NULL

    def create(self, word):
        cdef Node* new_node = <Node*>malloc(sizeof(Node*))
        if not new_node:
            raise MemoryError()

        new_node.word = word
        new_node.prev = NULL
        new_node.next = NULL

        if (self.head == NULL):
            self.head = new_node
            self.tail = new_node
        elif (self.head.word >= new_node.word):
            new_node.next = self.head
            self.head.prev = new_node
            self.head = new_node
        else:

            last_node = self.head
            next_node = self.head.next
            while (next_node != NULL):
                if (next_node.word >= new_node.word):
                    break
                last_node = next_node
                next_node = next_node.next

            new_node.prev = last_node
            new_node.next = next_node
            last_node.next = new_node

        if (next_node == NULL):
            self.tail = new_node
        else:
            next_node.prev = new_node
    
    def show_all(self):
        while (self.head != NULL):
            print(self.head.word)
            self.head = self.head.next
```

**testing_interface.py**

```
import program

algo = program.DoublyLinkedList()

algo.create(bytes("BRAIDEN", encoding="utf-8"))
algo.create(bytes("BRANT", encoding="utf-8"))
algo.create(bytes("KIM", encoding="utf-8"))
algo.create(bytes("DAVE", encoding="utf-8"))
algo.show_all()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`node.word` does not own it's own memory. It points into memory owned by a Python `bytes` object. That memory is valid only as long as the `bytes` object is alive.

Since you initialize it with a temporary that is passed to the constructor the memory is only valid for the duration of the constructor and no longer.

You either need to keep the `bytes` objects alive, or copy they contents into memory that you manage.

Comment: Thank you I just added variables to the calls to bytes() and subbed those variables into the function calls thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should allocate for one node, not for one pointer, to allocate a node.

In other words, the line

```
cdef Node* new_node = <Node*>malloc(sizeof(Node*))
```

should be

```
cdef Node* new_node = <Node*>malloc(sizeof(Node))
```

Comment: Thanks for writing in this has been changed on my copy, but I still will get multiple "DAVE" printed.